# In Rails 5, how do i define an application specific config variable?

Tags: initialization, config, ruby-on-rails-5, global

I'm using Rails 5.  How do I define a non-environment specific application configuration variable?  I tried creating this in config/initializers/global.rb

```
config.num_currencies_in_index = 12
```

but am greeted with this error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/config/initializers/global.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a module in initializers called `Constants` and then just define `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` under that namespace and use them in your app. This way you can't accidentaly override Rails config.

so your initializer would look like

```
module Constants
  NUM_CURRENCIES_IN_INDEX = 12.freeze
end
```

then you can use it in your code with `Constants::NUM_CURRENCIES_IN_INDEX`